# Doxygen documentation for the Boost libraries?

Tags: boost, documentation, doxygen

Is there doxygen documentation of the Boost libraries somewhere on the web?

I could create my own, but I think it should already exist somewhere on the web? Thanks!

Comment: Does the Boost (Graph) library have a Doxyfile in it somewhere? Then you could generate the documentation yourself. If not you can use Doxywizard(GUI wizard) to generate it for you. In the meantime you can also try using the [LXR generated documentation](http://acode-browser2.usatlas.bnl.gov/lxr-rel16/source/external/Boost_1.42.0_python2.6/boost-1_42/boost/graph/)

Comment: [Doxywizard howto](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/doxywizard_usage.html)

Answer (score 2):

There's a few sets of documentation.

The documentation for the current version of boost can be found **on the web** at the link below (with specific, older versions linked on the right-hand side).

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/

If you're after a **downloadable version of the HTML documentation**, then it's also contained in the boost distribution which you can download from the website. Open up the `index.html` file in the `libs` directory in your favourite browser.

Personally, I'd quite like a CHM file of the whole lot, but it seems these must be manually generated (boost don't provide them) with Doxygen and `hhc.exe` on Windows (which I don't use), so would appreciate any info on getting up-to-date CHMs of boost documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I generated some Doxygen output from Boost a while back.  It is hosted here:

http://charette.no-ip.com:81/programming/doxygen/boost/doxygen_notes.html

Answer (score 0):

The definitive Boost documentation are the docs available at boost.org. They tend to be quite good for most libraries.

What specific library is it that the docs are not sufficient for?

Comment: The Boost documentation is good in general. But I think the best source for information is actually the code itself, and that's best browsed through doxygen-generated HTML (I'm specifically looking to browse the Boost Graph code).

Comment: Boost.Graph actually has its own book. I think that is actually the definitive guide to the Boost.Graph library. I don't know of any doxygen documentation for Boost.

Answer (score 0):

The Boost libraries have quite a bit of template code and preprocessor macros. Doxygen does not understand templates or macros very well. I would stick to the standard boost documentation.

Comment: Wait, the STL has lots of templated code, and they have public doxygen documentation, which looks fine to me. Why would doxygen not understand Boost code?

Comment: Take a look at boost::function or boost::bind.
STL does not use templates like this.
Unless Doxygen has improved quite a bit from a year ago, i would not depend on it for quite a few of the boost libraries

Answer (score 0):

Though not doxygen based you may find the following site useful.
Boost Graph library (v1.42) online browsable LXR source code available [here](http://acode-browser2.usatlas.bnl.gov/lxr-rel16/source/external/Boost_1.42.0_python2.6/boost-1_42/boost/graph/). 
You can jump from definition to usage and vice-versa. 
To browse other boost components like bind, type_traits etc just navigate down the [main site](http://acode-browser2.usatlas.bnl.gov/lxr-rel16/source/external/Boost_1.42.0_python2.6/boost-1_42/boost)